# Can't send password recovery link using laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, email-validation

Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tsl://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Unable to find the socket transport "tsl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) then read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get the best answer possible.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a variety of settings, the MAIL ENCRYPTION = null would be my current assumption. Did you try to set MAIL ENCRYPTION = ssl to this? Because it is port 465, it might not be null or **tls** (the fallback of env)).

Answer (score 0):

After days of battling with this error i was able to find out the solution. In your .env file

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=myusername@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Then go to your config/mail  change the `'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail'),` hope this solve your problem too.